# rails RMagick - ImageMagik bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Anyone seen this happen?

```
$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.4 but ImageMagick 6.6.5-0 is in use. (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/bhellman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/bhellman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bhellman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/bhellman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bhellman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/rmagick.rb:11
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says it all: RMagick has been compiled against ImageMagick 6.6.4, but the latter one has been updated in the meantime.

Get an RMagick release that matches your new ImageMagick version, or just reinstall the gem, which will link against 6.6.5.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. ImageMagick isn't a gem it's install on the mac. RMagick is the gem

Comment: Reinstall the RMagick gem: it'll be recompiled against the newer ImageMagick version and won't complain anymore.